# convert json string to datetime format dd/mm/yyyy in django template

Tags: json, django, templates, view, django-templates

After using json.loads to get data and show it on django template, it give these results

```
Contract                   Name               Debt    Createat
20150307-500000-0009       AAA                   2   2020-12-13T14:25:35Z
20170221-0007429           BBB                   3   2020-12-13T14:25:35Z
```

I try to convert date time on createat column to dd/mm/yyyy, like this

```
Contract                   Name               Debt    Createat
20150307-500000-0009       AAA                   2   13/12/2020
20170221-0007429           BBB                   3   13/12/2020
```

In my view

```
        contract_posts = serializers.serialize('json', Contracts.objects.all())
        contract_posts = json.loads(contract_posts)
        request.session['contract_posts'] = contract_posts
        context = {'contract_posts': contract_posts}
        return render(request, 'customer2.html', context)
```

in my template

```
          {% for contract in contract_posts%}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ contract.fields.contract }}</td>
              <td>{{ contract.fields.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ contract.fields.debt }}</td>
              <td>{{ contract.fields.created_at}}
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

I try

```
<td>{{ contract.fields.created_at|date:"d m Y"}}
```

or

```
<td>{{ contract.fields.created_at|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"}}
```

But it just show empty cell in result

```
Contract                   Name               Debt    Createat
20150307-500000-0009       AAA                   2    
20170221-0007429           BBB                   3
```

my code in model.py

```
created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
objects=models.Manager()
class Meta:
    ordering=["-created_at"]
```

Comment: I don't think there is any need for 'fields': just write {{ contract.created_at|date:"d m Y" }}

Comment: @Ffion without "fields", I cannot load data to template. I try {{ contract.fields.created_at|date:"d m Y" }} but It still shows empty cell. I pass json string to template django

Comment: I do apologise, I just realised the values for the other fields are displaying fine, so that part of your HTML should be ok. Can you see your 'Contracts' instances in the Django Admin? Do they have values for created_at?

Comment: Please could you also clarify: is the date field called 'created_at' in your 'Contracts' Model definition?

Comment: @Ffion i just update my code. In django admin, values for created_at ="2020-12-13T14:25:35Z", but I need to convert to dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: I wonder if the issue is that you are passing JSON strings rather than objects that the date filter can be used on. You may need to do the date formatting on the server side. This is out of my comfort zone so hopefully this points you in the right direction or someone else can help!

Comment: You can seperate session data and query data. then you can apply filters easily.

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable send `json data` in `request.session` and send `query data` in view context. So it would be easy to apply django filters:

**views.py**

```
contract_posts = serializers.serialize('json', Contracts.objects.all())
c_p = json.loads(contract_posts)
request.session['contract_posts'] = c_p
context = {'contract_posts': contract_posts}
return render(request, 'customer2.html', context)
```

**template**

```
{% for contract in contract_posts %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ contract.contract }}</td>
      <td>{{ contract.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ contract.debt }}</td>
      <td>{{ contract.created_at|date:"d m Y"}}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```